# Azure service bus слишком медленный, особенно cold start

Tags: c#, azure, messaging

Имеется Azure service bus, tier - standard.

Очень медленно отправляется первое сообщения - до 20 секунд, последующие - в разброс, но до 200мс (что тоже медленно).
Можно ли с этим что-то сделать? Нужно птимизировать отправку простого сообщения.
Я уже готов расмотреть и другие опции в стеке ажура (blob queues).

```
using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus;

// this is reused and register as singleton
var connection = new ServiceBusConnection(connectionString);
var client = new QueueClient(connection, entity, ReceiveMode.PeekLock, null);

// first call - up to 20s
// next calls ~200 ms
await client.SendAsync(queueMessage);
```

Comment: Eсли метод `SendAsync` называется, то где `await`? [документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues). `var client` поменяйте на `IQueueClient client`, у вас наверняка методы экземпляра, а не интерфейса используются. Я не знаю, что там внутри, я просто вижу расхождения с документацией.

Comment: @aepot реальный метод асинхронный. Это просто вырезки.

Comment: это вводит в заблуждение, я же не могу догадаться, где у вас там синхронно, где асинхронно. Я просто вижу синхронны вызов на манер `async void` и предупреждаю об этом. А что с интерфейсам, зачем `var`, который берет возвращаемый тип, когда должен интерфейс быть? Это тоже в реальном методе по-другому?

Comment: @aepot добавил await дабы не смущать. Какая разница var там или нет? Как это может повлият на скорость?

Comment: `var` принимает возвращаемоый тип, то есть `QueueClient`, вам решать, есть разница между `QueueClient` и `IQueueClient`, используемом зачем-то в документации.

Comment: @aepot "вам решать" никак не может помочь найти ответ вопрос. И никакого негативного влияния на перфоманс от var/IQueueClient там быть не может.

Comment: Соглашусь, а вы проверили? Я сколько кода увидел, на столько и обратил внимание, чтобы провести более детальный анализ, нужно больше кода. В идеале воспроизводимый пример, но протестить его смогли бы только те, у кого есть доступ к аналогичному сервису. Попробуйте просмотреть трафик, например с помощью WireShark, можно будет хотя-бы понять, задержка возникает на стороне сервера, или на стороне вашего приложения.

Comment: [Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17987846/azure-service-bus-relay-response-slow) и [вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29425653/azure-service-bus-queue-extremely-slow) что нашел